# AWS login authentication after expiry of 12 hours

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, aws-ecr

I have docker swarm cluster of 5 nodes (3 Manager and 2 worker nodes).Deploying images from AWS ECR registry. 
Before starting services authenticating Docker with ECR using command `"aws ecr get-login -"` **on all the Swarm nodes**

**As the login token is valid only for 12 hours. To run the updated images after expiry of 12 hours am I required run `"aws ecr get-login -"` on all the Swarm nodes or only Leader node since docker service create is run only from Leader ?**

Answer (score 0):

No matter its docker in docker, nodes, the host machine or the VM if they want to pull the image for the first time they will need to login to ECR and will get the token to pull the rest of the images.

[image]

In your case, The Leader means the node is the primary manager node that makes all swarm management and orchestration decisions for the swarm, so better to take such tasks from the leader node.

AWS ECR login depended on the machine. If there are ten of images you need to pull from the ECR, you need to login and get token once in 12 hr only for the first time, you do not need to log in each and every time.

> Run the docker login command that was returned in the previous step.
>   This command provides an authorization token that is valid for 12
>   hours.

**Important**

> When you execute this docker login command, the command string can be
>   visible to other users on your system in a process list (ps -e)
>   display. Because the docker login command contains authentication
>   credentials, there is a risk that other users on your system could
>   view them this way. They could use the credentials to gain push and
>   pull access to your repositories. If you are not on a secure system,
>   you should consider this risk and log in interactively by omitting the
>   -p password option, and then entering the password when prompted.